# How do you have an event go every hour in roblox?

Tags: roblox

I want to create an hourly event in roblox, but I don't know how to script the wait for 1 hour.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want a `wait` statement and know how you want to do this with your loop already programmed, a `wait` statement lasting an hour is `wait(3600)`. Otherwise, here are some loop solutions that run code every hour according to the game or according to a time zone.

To run the script when the game starts, then do something every hour since then:

```lua
while true do
 -- this should be the code that runs every hour
 wait(3600)
end
```

To run according to UST (every time the minutes hit 0 in universal standard time):

```lua
while true do
 local timeTable = os.date("!*t", tick())
 if timeTable["min"] == "00" then
   -- this should be the code that runs every hour
 end
 wait(1)
end
```

To run according to the local time zone (this only works in LocalScripts to my knowledge):

```lua
while true do
 if os.date("%M", os.time()) == "00" then
  -- this should be the code that runs every hour
 end
 wait(1)
end
```

Comment: In your second example, does the `timeTable` variable need to be defined inside the while loop for it to be updated every `tick()`?